# a more simple way to code in php "if ( $x == $a[1] || $x == $a[2] || $x == $a[3] ....)

Tags: php, refactoring

As the title states, whats a more simple way to do

```
if ( $somevariable == $somearray[1] || $somevariable  == $somearray[3] || $somevariable  == $somearray[10] )
```

Seems like even with 3 variables.. there would be a shortcut.

I know this doesnt work, but something like would be nice:

```
if ($somevariable == $somearray[1],$somearray[3],$somearray[10]) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option

```
if ( in_array( $somevariable, array( $somearray[1], $somearray[3], $somearray[10] ) ) {}
```

Comment: This does assume he wants to check every value in the array which may not be the case.

Comment: @Nick - This is identical to his if statement, its also identical to your answer

Comment: I agree and you got my +1 but after looking at the question again he seems to be skipping around in the array - index 1, 3 then 10 and he never makes it clear he wants to compare against every value in it.

Comment: im not comparing against every value in it, just the indexes 1,3,10

Comment: cool. this is good to know!  how about if i wanted to do something like: if ( $somevariable == 'abcd' || $somevariable  == 'cdef' || $somevariable  == 'gfed' )

Comment: `if ( in_array( $somevariable, array( 'abcd', 'cdef', 'gfed' ) ) {}`

Comment: Might be wrong on this one, but doesn't in_array break once a matching value is found?  Short-circuit evaluation...think that's how it works.

Comment: @Alix Axel - yes it is the point.  @Nick in an earlier comment said "This does assume he wants to check every value...", which **wouldn't** happen as soon as in_array finds a match.  I guess I should have started my comment with @Nick to make that clear (sorry).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: seriously - I may have even got there first if I didn't stop to type the period.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your code is already all right.
If you don't want to dive into depths of *refactoring*, just leave it as is. Because:

- it does exactly what it's intended for - checks some variable against some conditions.
- more important: *it looks* like the code to check some variable against some conditions. So, you could always tell what does it do. That's way more important than some fancy shortland.

In pursue for conciseness, you should not forget *readability*.
The only solution acceptable is one which no less readable than your current one. Which *reads* (literally: if you read it aloud) like it's intentded.
Example: by making such a function,

```
function whateverCondition($variable,$array) {
  return ( $variable == $array[1] 
        || $variable  == $array[3] 
        || $variable  == $array[10]); 
}
```

you can call it later this way,

```
if (whateverCondition($somevariable,$somearray))
```

keeping **both** conciseness and readability (if you name it properly).

As it was mentioned in comments, parameters seems a bit redundant. it depends. if it's going to be a function, keep them in place.
if this function going to be a method of some appropriate *class* - you can omit them, making it

```
if ($user->meetCondition())
```

Comment: Why do you need the `$variable` and `$array` arguments?

Comment: This could actually be the best solution depending on the situation. +1 to offset.

Comment: @Galen: Currently the code is useless; `$variable` and `$array` have no effect. What part of this constitutes the "best solution"?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: It was a typo on his part, i knew what he was getting it. I fixed his typo.

Comment: It's basically just a rehash of the OP's code. However, the question is ambiguous. This might be what the OP was after: an easier way to swap out `$variable` and `$array`. However, if the indices of `$array` were what they were looking to be changeable, this code is just as bad as the OP's.

Comment: @Col: It's obvious that something is wrong with it, or else he wouldn't have brought it here.

Comment: @Simple LOL, no :) questions often being asked out of wrong assumptions

Comment: Still, giving them back essentially the same code they started with, just repackaged in a new function, is of no use.

Comment: @Simple thank you for sharing your opinion but I can judge the matter myself.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that well-named functions are worth writing, even when the function body might be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [`array_intersect_key()`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
if (in_array($var, array_intersect_key($somearray, array_flip(array(1, 3, 10)))))
{
}
```

This is mostly useful if you have a large numbers of indexes to check.

---

In a variadic function, as @knittl suggested:

```
function in_array_keys($needle, $haystack)
{
    $keys = array_flip(array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    return in_array($needle, array_intersect_key($haystack, $keys)));
}

var_dump(in_array_keys($var, $somearray, 1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: it's most puzzling way if you happen to read this code some time later and wonder what is supposed to do.

Comment: elegant and concise … wrapped in a function and we're good to go